# ASP (Classic) on Linux Chilisoft Replacement

Tags: apache, asp-classic, sunone

Sun's One Server worked great up until Sun Disappeared. 
Now looking around the landscape the classic ASP solutions are all abadoned.

Apache::ASP appears to be perl wrapped in ASP tags. 
Chilisoft ASP no longer exists. Old versions won't compile against new Apache 2. 
Sun's package solution doesn't even have a support page anymore.

Where did everyone with ASP code running on a unix server run to?
Is it time to pay the outdated code tax?

Comment: I second this question...I was able to find a Sun One ASP 4.0.2 package that should be compatible with RHEL/Centos 3. They say that during installation it no longer asks for a serial number/license, but I suspect is anyway needed..if it's an Out Of Life product why there's no way of getting a download and license number to use? I think we are not the only ones still needing this platform...and the Chilisoft/Sun/Oracle exchanges left us with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one: http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Mod_Mono is an Apache 2.0/2.2 module that provides ASP.NET support for the web's favorite server, Apache.

The module passes off requests for ASP.NET pages to an external program, mod-mono-server, which actually handles the requests. The communication between the Apache module and mod-mono-server is established using a Unix socket or a TCP socket.

Comment: Mono is a great project.  But as covered here it does not support asp it supports .net or .aspx type applications.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501295/running-asp-classic-and-net-on-linux Unfortunately mono does not support classic asp apps.